# laravel retry when DB not reachable

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel

I have a DB that autoscales. It is sometimes not reachable for a few seconds during scaling.

Laravel then returns a 500 server error. Is it possible to keep retrying for a certain amount of time rather than returning 500?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    try{
        DB::connection('connection-name')->...;
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {
        usleep(400);

        DB::connection('connection-name')->...;
    }
```

Comment: Can I somehow apply this to all eloquent queries or would I need to wrap all my existing ones with the try/catch.